# How can I use future forecasts as input variable in a LSTM model for time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

General question that I can't really find any answer on, only hints that it's possible:

Let's say I want to predict future sales.

```
y(t+1) = sales at day t+1 (t+1 = next day)
```

And I have two input variables; historical sales and historical weather forecast.

```
x1(t) = historical sales day t
x2(t) = historical weather forecast for day t
```

After trained a model, I can predict y(t+1).

BUT, how can I use future looking data for weather as an input? I have already a weather forecast for day t+1 that would affect my sales and that I would like to use as input - in this case x2(t+1). Like this:

```
Output:
y(t+1)

Input:
x1(t)
x2(t)
x2(t+1) <------
```

**Is it possible to incorporate this feature in a LSTM model? If so, how would the input matrix look like for training and using the model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite correct. You can supply current weather and previous sales as input to predict current sales.

```
sales[t+1] = RNN(weather[t+1], sales[t]) <-- [Correct]
```

However, supplying previous weather isn't necessary as relevant information will be propagated through hidden features.

```
sales[t+1] = RNN(weather[t+1], weather[t], sales[t]) <-- [Wrong]
```

**Example**

Let this be our sample data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'weather':1, 'sales':500}, {'weather':3, 'sales':200}, {'weather':2, 'sales':400}, {'weather':0, 'sales':600}])
print(df)

   weather  sales
0        1    500
1        3    200
2        2    400
3        0    600
```

We have to generate a training input with specific dimensions.

```
#Training input dimensions = (No. of training samples, seq_length, No. of features)

seq_len = 3 #Number of times the LSTM loops
n_features = 2 # weather and sales are considered as input

training_input = torch.zeros((df.shape[0], seq_len, n_features))
row = torch.zeros(seq_len, n_features)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row[:-1] = row[1:]
    prev_sales = df.sales[i-1] if i > 0 else 0 #i.e., sales[-1] = 0
    row[-1, :] = torch.tensor([df.weather[i], prev_sales])
    training_input[i] = row

print(training_input)

tensor([[[  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  1.,   0.]],

        [[  0.,   0.],
         [  1.,   0.],
         [  3., 500.]],

        [[  1.,   0.],
         [  3., 500.],
         [  2., 200.]],

        [[  3., 500.],
         [  2., 200.],
         [  0., 400.]]])
```

The following section is an example about supplying the training input to an LSTM layer.

Initialize LSTM parameters

```
input_size = 2 #weather and previous sales are considered as input
hidden_size = 2 #any number can be used
n_layers = 1 #number of LSTMs stacked. In this case, only 1 LSTM is used
batch_size = training_input.size()[0] #passing entire training input in one go
```

Initialize hidden_input

```
hidden_input = torch.zeros(n_layers,batch_size,hidden_size), torch.zeros(n_layers,batch_size, hidden_size)
```

Create LSTM layer

```
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size,hidden_size)
```

Training input has to be reshaped according to the accepted input dimensions of the forward function in LSTM class.

```
lstm_input = training_input.view(seq_len,batch_size,input_size)
out, hidden = lstm(lstm_input, hidden_input)

print(out[-1])

tensor([[2.0370e-10, 9.6134e-07],
    [2.2299e-25, 7.1835e-28],
    [2.0600e-10, 1.1409e-06],
    [8.0952e-21, 1.2101e-24]], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

For more information refer the [Pytorch documentation for LSTM layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm). Hope this helps.